# Sharepoint Custom Configuration

Tags: configuration

Please let me know how do I store custom configuration XML files in SharePoint? Like the way we do in ASP.NET applications with App.config.

Answer (score 3):

Are you on premises or in sharepoint online?

**If on premises:**
In the hive (14 or 15 depending on your SP version) there is a folder named CONFIG

You can map this folder to your Visual Studio solution, just like you map in Layouts and Images, and then place your configuration XML there

Comment: it is on premisses.How do I map the config folder to my VS.NET?

Comment: You should really just use the SharePoint folders for SharePoint Projects in VS. Right click your project, add mapped folder, other, and point at the config folder. Have no acces to my environments right now, so theses steps are not 100% but you should be able to find it

Comment: Cheers Robert. Got it now.

Comment: Please mark as answer if it helped you